# Why does the writer use "away from" in "hauling earth away from an excavation site" instead of just "from"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

> Vehicles are hauling earth away from an excavation site.

Why does the writer use "away from"? Can I use "from" instead of "away from"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [5 miles from vs. 5 miles AWAY from](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/91383/5-miles-from-vs-5-miles-away-from)

Answer (score 4):

**"Hauling earth from an excavation site"** is correct, but has the sense that that the earth is being moved to be used somewhere else. **"Hauling earth away from a site"** has the sense that the earth is being moved out of the way and it doesn't really matter where it is going to be deposited.