# 5 miles from vs. 5 miles AWAY from

Tags: adverbs, phrase-choice

> I had to get off the bus 5 miles from where I was supposed to.
>
> I had to get off the bus 5 miles **away** from where I was supposed to.

Here, do both the sentences mean the same?
Does **away** hold any real significance here?

Answer (score 1):

Other than contributing a slightly greater emphasis on the distance, the meaning here is generally the same. **Both usages are interchangeable**, with the possible exception of *"away"* being used in some cases to denote that the overall direction of travel to a midpoint (B) would put you farther from the destination (C) than your point of origin:

> We could head to the pharmacy in Anytown, but that would put us thirty miles *away* from our destination.

In speech, the presence of *"away"* (along with contrarian *"but that"* as opposed to *"which"*) would seem to indicate that the direction traveled from point A to point B is unfavorable to the direction traveled toward the final destination (C), *especially* if you place a verbal emphasis on the word *"away"* when speaking.

However, there are a few other ways to convey this:

> - We could head to the pharmacy in Anytown, but that would put us thirty miles from our destination in the opposite direction.
> - We could head to the pharmacy in Anytown, but that would put us fifteen miles further away from our destination.

These are slightly less ambiguous ways to convey that a course of action is counterproductive to the direction of travel.

(***Side note:*** Replacing "but that" with "which" in the final two examples above would also be grammatically correct, but it would change the meaning of the sentence to suggest that moving in a direction further away from your destination would be a favorable course of action, which would seem illogical.)

Comment: I am not sure *contrarian* is the right word to describe "but that". Contrastive maybe?